# ArcGIS JS - Feature Layer selection symbol before layers loaded

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a feature layer that is dynamic and could pull a

`geometryType: esriGeometryPoint`

or

`geometryType: esriGeomertyPolygon`

I was wondering how would I know when to set the selection symbol to

`new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(...)`

or

`new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(...)`

Before I was able to just set the selection symbol to `new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(...)` and it would fill the polygon symbol.  But now something seems to have changed where it now just places a circle or marker symbol in its place.

I've tried to set the selection symbol on `featureLayer.on("load", function (evt) { ... })`, but it just seems to use the default color of the layer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some digging I found the answer to my question.

When the `featureLayer` is loaded `featureLayer.on("load", function (evt) { ... })` follow these steps:

1. Suspend drawing on the layer `featuerLayer.suspend()`
2. Set your selection symbol `featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(...)`
3. Resume drawing on the layer `featureLayer.resume()`

Hope this helps someone out.